# How to add an item containing sub-items in each iteration of a loop?

Tags: php, html

Sorry if this seems very simple I'm rather new to php.

I'm drawing data from the database using a for each loop and want to add a list item for each result to a side bar while adding a new container `div` to the body.

What is the best way to code this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks A

Edit...

My code so far...

```
<?php  

$iidcoversheets = $wpdb->get_results( 
                "
                SELECT * 
                FROM $wpdb->trm_iid_cover_sheet
                WHERE Return_ID_FK = '$trmrtnid->Return_ID_PK'
                "
            );
$gadcoversheets = $wpdb->get_results( 
                "
                SELECT * 
                FROM $wpdb->trm_gad_cover_sheet
                WHERE Return_ID_FK = '$trmrtnid->Return_ID_PK'
                "
            );
 ?>
        <ul>
        <?php    
            foreach ( $iidcoversheets as $iidcoversheet ) 
            {
        ?>
                <li><?php echo $iidcoversheet->business name; ?></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
            foreach ( $gadcoversheets as $gadcoversheet ) 
            {
        ?>
                <li><?php echo $gadcoversheet->business name; ?></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
```

I understand how to add the `<li>` items but I'm strugging on how to add a div containing some html to another `div` not in the `<ul>` tag as it seems to me this will interrupt the code for the `<ul>`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks A

Comment: Please, post the code you have done so far, so we can help from there.

Comment: I can't imagine any PHP tutorial that doesn't include something like this. Go back to the books.

Comment: Don’t `echo` out all of your HTML code inside the loop, but put it into string variables instead, so that you can output those afterwards anywhere and in any order you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, solved it as per my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I came to the realisation that I could simply do another exact same loop later on in the page in the `div` I wanted but with different output. I was trying to do it all up front save the results and output them somewhere else, unnecessary.

Clearly I was having a daft moment earlier.

Thanks for all the input.

Regards

A

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<ol>
<?php
    foreach ($uls as $ul) {
    ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo $ul; ?>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
?>
</ol>
</div>
```